# Using the exponential distribution to model time between inconsecutive events in a Poisson process

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-function, poisson-distribution

if $X \sim Poisson (\lambda=A)$ then $T$, the time between two **consecutive** events in such process $\sim Exp(\beta=\frac{1}{\lambda})$ how about if we are trying to model the time between the $i_{th}$ and the $j_{th}$ event?

Comment: What do you know about the Gamma distribution?

Comment: Umm. actually, we haven't gone through it, I needed an answer for this question to be able to answer iii) here: https://imgur.com/a/hSt7vBk, so we can't solve this by standalone knowledge of the exponential distribution?

Comment: Hint: It's a sum of independent exponential variables.